# overflow? as container size gets bigger, elements get pushed out

Tags: html, css

When i change the css in ".container" from "width:800px" to "width:1900px"  all the elements go out of whack.  and the orange box keeps leaning towards the left side instead of being centered.  anyone know why this is happening?  my friend said it might have something to do with overflow, but he wasn't sure.

Picture1: width:1900px

Picture 2:width 800px
HTML:

```
        <div id="orangeBox">

            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Dash Logo" id="logo" />

            <div id="snappyText">
                <p>Ever think,"Where are the most mediocre places to eat around here? I want me some of that."</p>
            </div>  

            <div id="response">
                <p>Yeah, neither do we.</p>
            </div>

            <img src="images/whiteLine.png" alt="White Line" id="whiteLine" />

            <img src="images/iphone.png" alt="iPhone" id="iphone" />

            <img src="images/videoScreenshot.png" alt="Video Screenshot" id="videoScreenshot" />

            <img src="images/appStoreWhite.png" alt="App Store" id="appStoreWhite" />

            <div id="explanatoryText">
                <p>Dash is the quickest way to find good places to eat. In a world with too many choices and too much information, Dash clears the clutter and offers only the best in your area.</p> 
            </div>

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="http://boxoutdev.com/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/thedashapp"><img src="images/twitterGray.png" alt="twitter" id="twitterGray" /></a>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebookGray.png" alt="facebook" id="facebookGray" /></a>

        </div><!--end orangebox-->
    </div><!--end container-->
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: url(images/grayBackground.png);
}

/*orangeBox*/

#orangeBox{
    background-image:url(images/orangeBackground.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}




.container{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

[image: width:1900px]

[image: width:800px]

Comment: There's no #container opening tag in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you change your css to this

```
min-width:800px;
    width:auto;
```

try if it works.